# Problem in finding radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{n+2}{n})^{n^2}x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series

Clearly, the radius of convergence is $r=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}|=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n+3}{n+1})^{(n+1)^2}(\frac{n+2}{n})^{n^2}$

I proceeded as follows: 
$(\frac{n+3}{n+1})^{(n+1)^2}(\frac{n}{n+2})^{n^2}=(\frac{n(n+3)}{(n+2)(n+1)})^{n^2}(\frac{n+3}{n+1})^{2n+1}=(1+\frac{-2}{(n+2)(n+1)})^{n^2}(1+\frac{2}{n+1})^{2n+1}=(1+\frac{-2}{(n+2)(n+1)})^{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{-2}\frac{-2}{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)}}(1+\frac{2}{n+1})^{\frac{n+2}{2}\frac{2(2+1/n)}{1+2/n}}\to e^{-2}.e^4=e^2$ 
So the radius of convergence should be $e^2$. However, the answer given is $e^{-2}$. Either the answer given is wrong or something in my calculation. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You calculated $\frac{1}{R}$. See formula at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: You miscalculated the inverse of $x_{n}$ in $|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}|$.

Comment: @zkutch: Yes. You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

It is simpler here to use *Hadamard's formula*:
$$\frac 1R=\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}=\limsup\Bigl(\frac{n+2}n\Bigr)^{\!n}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that, if $$x_n = \left( \frac{n+2}{n} \right)^{n^2} = \frac{(n+2)^{n^2}}{n^{n^2}}$$

then

$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \underbrace{\frac{(n+3)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{(n+1)^2}}}_{\displaystyle x_{n+1}} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{n^{n^2}}{(n+2)^{n^2}}}_{\displaystyle 1/x_n}$$

as opposed to your calculation. (Also, $r$ should be $1$ divided by the limit you calculated.)

Comment: That was a typo in the post. However, all my calculations are based upon the correct $x_n$. I realize after going over comments that the mistake is to consider $r=\lim |x_{n+1}|/|x_n|$ as radius of convergence as radius of convergence is $y=r^{-1}$